# Angular regular expression shouldn't allow negative numbers but it allows negative whole numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I've got the following regular expression: `^(?!0*(\.0+)?$)[0-9]{0,9}(\.[0-9]{1,4})?$`

When testing this in online regular expression builders for javascript it works as expected, but when I use it in my angular application (angular 4) it is allowing negative whole numbers when it shouldn't.

From my understanding this regular expression should allow any positive number above zero up to 4 decimal places and up to 9 digits before the decimal, meaning exactly zero is not a match and any negative number is not a match, and anything that's not a number isn't a match.

Why is angular making something like '-32' become a match? '-32.2' is invalid as it should be. How can I change this to make angular happy?

I am using it in a reactive form like so:

```
let regExNotZero =  new RegExp('^(?!0*(\.0+)?$)[0-9]{0,9}(\.[0-9]{1,4})?$');
...
Quantity: [item.quantity, Validators.pattern(regExNotZero)
...
```

Quantity is just a control inside a form group using reactive forms in angular.

Comment: How are you using it in angular? Also, did you try using a character class -- eg `\d` instead of `0-9` ?

Comment: Angular itself doesn't really affect the way regular expressions work in JavaScript. That regular expression works fine. How exactly are you using it? In particular, does it appear in your code as a JavaScript regular expression literal, or is it a string? If it's a string, what (again, what *exactly*) does it look like?

Comment: I've updated my question to show how I'm using it. When I test this regular expression in an online regular expression builder -32.34 and -32 are both not matches which is what I expect. When using it in my angular app, using the exact same regular expression, the -32 whole number does not say it's invalid.

Comment: Your regex can be shortened to `^(?![0.]+$)\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,4})?$`

Comment: Then the first sentence of your question is wrong. You don't have that regex. Did you look at what `regExNotZero` actually is?

Comment: Hmmmm interesting. After doing a console.log(regExNotZero) I see the regex has changed to /^(?!0*(.0+)?$)[0-9]{0,9}(.[0-9]{1,4})?$/ and putting that in the online regex builder it does the behavior that I see in my angular app. Even though it was built using the regex that I put in the first sentence of my question.

Comment: @Kevin, you need to escape your backslashes. Seems you already answered your own question though

Comment: You can also use the literal notation: `let regExNotZero = /^(?:[1-9]\d{0,8}(?:\.\d{1,4})?|\.(?=.*[1-9])\d{1,4})$/;`

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change it to `^(?!0*(\\.0+)?$)[0-9]{0,9}(\\.[0-9]{1,4})?$`

The double back slash is required, without it javascript is trying to treat things after the back slash as special characters.